# \tableofcontents overwrites default header

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I am using Springer's svmult package. The default header gives the name of the author in the top right corner and the title in the top left. When I use \tableofcontents, the default header is overwritten with "Contents" in both sides of the page.

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}

\begin{document}

\title*{Contribution Title}

 \author{Name of First Author and Name of Second Author}
 \maketitle
 \abstract*{Each chapter should be preceded by an abstract (10--15 lines long)}

 \tableofcontents

 \section{Section Heading}
 \label{sec:1}
 Use the template \emph{chapter.tex} together with the Springer document class SVMono
 \section{Section Heading}
 \label{sec:2}
 \subsection{Subsection Heading}
 \label{subsec:2}
 \subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading}
 \section{Section Heading}
 \label{sec:3}
 \subsection{Subsection Heading} %
 In order to avoid simply listing headings of different levels...
 \subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading}
 \end{document}
```

So I am getting something like Fig.1. 
[image: Fig1]

But what I want is something like Fig.2
[image: Fig2]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your code is much too long for a question on this site. You must narrow down the problem and edit your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Downvoters, please give the OP a chance to make amends and edit his question into a digestible form. Downvoting a question into oblivion is only necessary for spam.

Comment: Thank you @Jubobs. I hope the edited code is suitable. Please let me know if you want me to make any other changes

Comment: I realize that a couple of packages are unnecessary, but I am not sure what is causing the problem. The template is straight out of the author template from Springer's SVMult class.

Comment: That's fine; your code isn't too long now. Ideally, though, you should try to identify (by trial and error) all the packages that are irrelevant to your question and discard them from your MWE. That's part of the personal research we expect from you before you ask a question on the site.

Comment: Thank you. I have taken out all the packages now and the problem still persists.

Comment: I cannot see any problem. However the `svmult` class sets the `tocdepth` to 0, so there is something missing in your example.

Comment: @Herbert The header in page 4 says "Contents". Ideally, it should be the title in the left page and author name in the right page.

Comment: `Contents` is correct, but it is empty. You have to add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` into the preamble to get a table of contents.

Comment: @Herbert I am getting a table of contents but my problem is with the headers, which get overwritten to "Contents". I have attached two images which I hope makes the problem clearer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
 ...
 \tableofcontents
 \markboth{\leftmark}{\rightmark}
 ...
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution when the table of contents is entirely contained within a single page.  However, it doesn't appear to work when the table of contents spans more than one page: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/665052/139330

Answer (score 2):

```
\frontmatter [u need this]
\maketitle
\preface
\lipsum
\tableofcontents


\mainmatter [u need this]

[document]


\backmatter   [u need this]
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is doing or is supposed to do. Only the code could be very hard to understand ...  BTW: Welcome to TEX.SE!

Comment: You have to divide your file to 3 parts, when you use svmult.

Comment: First one with title, toc and abastract should have \frontmatter command written before it. The whole main part of document should have \mainmatter command written before it. After this command there should appear regular document structures like chapters and sections. The third part is precedesed by command \backmatter and sholud be insterted before appendix and blibliography. Those 3 commands tells svmult how to create TOC.

Comment: You should use the "edit" button to edit your answer and add an explanation of the code inside the answer rather than in the comments. Welcome to TeX.SX!